# How to populate a table with vertical and horizontal results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
HeaderA HeaderB HeaderA HeaderB
 stuff    232     hey     3434
 world    033     boy     221
 bat      435     girl    930
```

This table is dynamic and gets populated live. Here's my JS code, but the logic is not working correctly. I need to tell it that every 2 columns is a new record, and make a new row every 4th column. Here's what I have so far:

```
function html_data(data) {
  var html = '';

  $.each(data, function (index, value) {
    if ((index+1) % 4 == 0 && index != 0) {
        html += '<td>'+value+'</td>';
        html += '</tr>'
    } else if ((index+1) % 5 == 0) {
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td>'+value+'</td>';
    } else {
        html += '<td>'+value+'</td>';
    }
        html += '</tr>';
  });

  return html;
}
```

Obviously the above code is completely wrong, but that's all I have so far. If I can the get the mod logic, I can fill in the blanks.

Comment: What is data structure for data object?

Comment: You can just use `value.headerA` and `value.headerB`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/G3JK5/

HTML

```
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <th>HeaderA</th>
        <th>HeaderB</th>
        <th>HeaderA</th>
        <th>HeaderB</th>
        <th>HeaderA</th>
        <th>HeaderB</th>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Add some random data" />
```

Javascript

```
//Sample usage
var tbl = new weirdTable('table');

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    tbl.addData([
        parseInt(Math.random() * 100),
        parseInt(Math.random() * 100)
    ]);
});
```

weirdTable

```
function weirdTable(tableId){
    var _me = null;

    var _currentIndex = 0;
    var _colCount     = 0;
    var _lastRowIndex = 0;

    var construct = function(tableId){
        _me = document.getElementById(tableId);
        _colCount = _me.rows[0].cells.length;
        _currentIndex = _colCount;
    };

    this.addData = function(data){
        var row = _me.rows[_lastRowIndex];

        //or var data = arguments;
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            if(_currentIndex >= _colCount){
                _lastRowIndex++;
                _currentIndex = 0;
                row = _me.insertRow(_lastRowIndex);
            }        

            row.insertCell(_currentIndex).innerText = data[i];
            _currentIndex++;
        }
    };

    construct(tableId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, you can just do this:

```
if (index%4===0) { // start of a row
    html += '<tr>';
}
html += '<td>'+value+'</td>';
if (index%4===3) { // end of row
    html += '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: This worked fine, but how do I add a `</tr>` if the last record is not even. What if I only have 3 records?

Comment: Also, this doesn't take into account that I have vertical results.

Comment: I don't know what "vertical results" means. You haven't told us what your `data` looks like.

Comment: It means that instead of having each record on a new line, I have them on every other column. So my results go vertically on every other column (provided a sample output).